# Смена url во время проксирования nginx

Tags: nginx

Не могу найти, как поменять(обрезать) url. У меня есть сервер, который запущен в докере, и мне необходимо перенаправлять на него запросы начинающиеся с /api/v/..., но чтобы запрос был не /api/v1/some_method, а /some_method. Можно как-то вырезать эту часть (/api/v)?

```
{
   location / {
       работа с клиентом
   }
   location /api/v1 {
       например запрос '/api/v1/api_method'
       я его обрезаю до '/api_method' и перенаправляю на адрес докера
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему с помощью rewrite

```
location /api/v1 {
    rewrite ^/api/v1(.*)$ $1 break;
    Обычная настройка прокси через proxy_pass
}
```